# Track Custom Models

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

can it be possible to track custom model on retrieve on entity framework core.

say i am scaffold the database to the context int Entity Framework Core 3.1 it allow me to put a general configuration on **Tracking** or **Not Tracking**

```
optionBuilder.UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.TrackAll);
optionBuilder.UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking);
```

these are the only two option.

can i implement something to Track only the table on retrieve and skip the views,
and what i am taking about is something automatic not the extension method
`.AsNoTracking()` or `.AsTracking()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views should not tracked by default. Take a look at [Keyless Entity Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types?tabs=data-annotations):

> Keyless entity types characteristics:
>
> - Cannot have a key defined.
> - Are never tracked for changes in the DbContext and therefore are never inserted, updated or deleted on the database.
>
> [...]

Just add `.HasNoKey()` to the model definition of the type, and you are good to go:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder
        .Entity<BlogPostsCount>(eb =>
        {
            eb.HasNoKey();
            eb.ToView("View_BlogPostCounts");
        });
}
```

#### Preserving model definitions over multiple scaffolder runs

When scaffolding more than once, the `OnModelCreating` method will be overwritten every time and custom changes will be lost.

However, the scaffolder creates the context class as `partial` and also explicitly generates a `partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)` method.

So to keep your custom changes when scaffolding again, just create a `partial class` with the same name as the original context class and implement your custom changes in the `OnModelCreatingPartial` method.

For example, if the scaffolder creates a context class named `MyContext`, then you can define the following class in *another file*:

```cs
public partial class MyContext : DbContext
{
    partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // Your custom changes to the mode.
        modelBuilder.Entity<BlogPostsCount>(eb =>
        {
            eb.HasNoKey();
            eb.ToView("View_BlogPostCounts");
        });
    }
}
```

For more information on `partial`, see [Partial Classes and Methods (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods).

Comment: another simple question please . can i edit the updated dbcontext model builder in ef core with out override it in the next scaffolding

Comment: I updated my answer with the answer to your second question.